# Duplicate Cache-Control header inserted when I setup filter bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I setup a filter bean to insert and reset `Cache-Control` headers. This is working fine, except at little point after the filter, extra `Cache-Control` headers are being inserted.

I'm working with `Spring Boot`.
Any solution on what could be causing the issue?

```
@Component
public class CacheControlFilter implements Filter {

     @Override
     public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

     @Override
     public void destroy() {}

     @Override
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        Calendar expires = Calendar.getInstance();
        expires.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);

        // Intercept response header
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", expires.getTimeInMillis());
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=2048");
        chain.doFilter(request, resp);
     }
}
```

See the duplicate `Cache-Control` headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
...  
Cache-Control: max-age=2048  
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate  
Expires: Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:21:30 GMT  
Expires: 0  
Pragma: no-cache  
Content-Type: image/png  
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Spring-security?

Spring security will automatically add them as well, you can disable them in your config as follows:

```
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //... Rest of config

        http.headers().disable()
```

See here for details:  http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HeadersConfigurer.html

You can also configure specific headers to be on/off as required (see other methods in that API doc, for example `cacheControl()` etc)

Comment: Do you have debug capabilities in your IDE?  If you turn logging to TRACE and add some breakpoints in the filters that are being invoked you should be able to find out where it is getting added (assuming that you are confident that there isnt application code elsewhere setting the header)

Comment: also can you show us the security config? is there just one security config file?

Comment: FOI - One should also remove `spring.resources.cache-period` property within application.properties file to disable `Spring boot` from adding its default cache-control headers.